# Php code is not executing instead displaying in web browser

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

I am not using any Xampp or wampp, I have manually installed and configured all the software bellow:

```
apache
php
phpmyadmin
mysql
```

I even tested if the php is working correctly by creating a 'test.php' file in the "C:/Apache/htdocs" folder of apache and it was working properly.

**Issue:**
I am creating registration form, I have attached the connect.php to index.html which are present inside the folder "C:/Apache/htdocs/Test" but the ***php code is not executing instead the content of .php file is displaying in the browser.***

```
<?php
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];

    // Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','abcdefg','test');
    if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "$conn->connect_error";
        die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(firstName, lastName, gender, email, password, number) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $firstName, $lastName, $gender, $email, $password, $number);
        $execval = $stmt->execute();
        echo $execval;
        echo "Registration successfully...";
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

connection in .html file:

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <form action="connect.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Can you try with change index.html to index.php ?

Comment: You tested if PHP is working in the `htdocs` folder, but it seems that it does not work in your `htdocs/Test` folder. This would be a configuration error in your `apache`.

Comment: Do you have any idea where might the configuration went wrong?, https://youtu.be/cm5L2EXA_t4 the link i followed for configuration.

Comment: I have even tried keeping both .html and .php file in htdocs itself and still facing the same  issue.

Comment: changing index.html to index.php worked, you saved my day :) @OmarFaruque

Answer (score -2):

It appears that the document for the apache does not have any php integration or the php service is not running in that specific directory.

Comment: The whole php code(which i pasted in the question) is displaying in web browser after I run .html

Comment: would you share the version of php and apache you are using?